Boolean Attribute Issue in Decision Split Activity in a Shared Data Extension
I'm using a boolean attribute in a shared data extension in the decision split activity in the journey. The business unit I'm using is a child business unit.
However, I noticed that the boolean value is always null even when there is a value. It seems this basic functionality should work, but it is not. Could you please help me with this?
Thanks

Is the entry data source in the journey also the shared Data Extension?

Hi @Duc, Not its not a Shared Data Extension and the entry source is API EVENT. As I can see If I'm using the contact data, all the attributes are null, but the journey data is working fine.

Have you created the attribute group between the journey entry DE and the shared DE then use it in the decision split?

Yes, it is. I created several attribute groups and checked, but it's same result. I have created a case with Salesforce support.
